# Firebase Audience not showing details

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

There are already multiple questions with the same title but I believe this one is different.

I have created 2 audiences.

One for ***app_exception*** event.

[image]

And, one for ***app_remove*** event.

[image]

When I check these events for a specific date range, ***Sep 19, 2016 - Sep 21, 2016*** (btw I created audiences on 19th), I can see that I have more than 10 users for each of them.

[image]

However, when I check Audiences, it shows me less than 10 for both of them.

[image]

On other questions this can be answered as "The threshold of 10 is actually based on Advertising Identifiers (and not Analytics "users")." but I don't think that this is valid for my case, because, it is really highly unlikely that less than 10 different people installed and removed the app more than 40 times.

So, what could be the reason for this?

Comment: Is it still the case right now ? Audiences are updated every 24 hours so maybe you just had to wait a bit. Also if you filter event from september 20 to 21 (or 22 now) do you still have more than 10 people uninstalling the app ?
It's unlikely but maybe 38 of the 47 event where from september 19 but a couple of hours/minute before you created the audience :/ who knows :/

Comment: @Sistr I can see some data right now, but data in the audiences and events definitely not matching for any date range. I started to feel FA is useless.

Comment: @Sistr Audiences are updated when reports update (every 4-5 hours).

Answer (score 1):

There is currently an issue where app_remove-based audiences are under-counting in the case where users uninstall your app very shortly after launching it for the first time. This is the likely cause here.

Comment: Right now, I can see some numbers, which just don't match with the numbers under events. So in the events section, it is not under-counting but it is under-counting in the audiences section, is this the case?

Comment: @guneykayim is what Steve mean by "app_remove-based audience ...". Hopefully it'll get fixed soon (^_^)

Comment: @Sistr yeah but that "app_remove-based audience" is based on "app_remove" event, how can it get under-counted while the event itself is not? Or for audiences they don't get the data from the event itself and collect data separately from the event?

Comment: My understanding is that what you are describing is the "issue". The answer to: "how can it get under-counted while the event itself is not?" => Due to a bug somewhere in Firebase data processing pipeline.

Comment: Any answers to my questions in the comments?

Comment: @steve it has been 2 and half years. Is the bug fixed? Because Firebase Audience is still undercounting for app_remove audience for one of my project.